# Mutiple buttons on MVC form - get item id in the action controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a list of items. Each item have a textbox and a button. 
What is the best way to get the item id of the button clicked in the controller action?
I need the value from the associated textbox in the controller action, so I do not think I can use action links.

Comment: are you familiar with javascript or jQuery? - can this answer be in jQuery ? and what do you mean by you need the value of the textbox? where do you need it?

Comment: please post your HTML

Comment: @ScottSelby - He means he needs to submit the form, that's why he says he doesn't think he can use action links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  Some use javascript, others don't.  I personally prefer to NOT use javascript for basic functionality, unless your design is itself javascript based (such as using ajax)

For instance, you can have each item be wrapped in it's own form, with a different submit value.  Just be careful not to nest forms, as that's not valid HTML.

For instance:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { id=1 })) {
    <input type="submit"/>
    @Html.TextBox("TheValue", "One")
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { id=2 })) {
    <input type="submit"/>
    @Html.TextBox("TheValue", "Two")
}

public ActionResult MyAction(int? id, string TheValue) {
     // if they click the first one, id is 1, TheValue = "One"
     // if they click the second one, id is 2, TheValue = "Two"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer is using jquery - If you do not know how to add jQuery to your view or just simply  do not want to use it let me know and I can re-work the answer

I would do something like this

```
<li>
   <input type="text" id="1" name="1" class="whatever" />
   <input type="button" value="CliCk mE" class="myButton" />
</li>
<li>
   <input type="text" id="2" name="2" class="whatever" />
   <input type="button" value="CliCk mE" class="myButton" />
</li>
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenText" name="myHiddenText" />
```

then add this jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('.myButton').click(function(){
       // this is how to get the closest textbox
       // you didn't show your html , maybe .prev() or .next()
       var textValue = $(this).closest("input[type='text']").val();

       // this sets your hidden field with the value from desired textbox
       $('#myHiddenText').val(textValue);
    });
});
</script>
```

now when you submit this form to server you can just use myHiddenText on the server

```
    public ActionResult Index(string myHiddenText = "")
    {
        // hidden fields in the HTML form automatically get passed to server on submit
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Have been down that road, but was not able to make it work.

My code:

<input id="Testing" name="Testing" type="text" value="" /><input id="CurrentId" name="CurrentId" type="hidden" value="" /><input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Testing" />

Comment: And script And script

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.myButton').click(function () {
                alert("Here");
                var textValue = $(this).closest("input[type='text']").val();
                alert(textValue);
                // this sets your hidden field with the value from desired textbox
                $('#CurrentId').val(textValue);
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: I get "here" from the first alert, but undefined from the next :(

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use jquery but if you only want to use c# I would suggest the following:

I imagine you are using some sort of repeating statement (for or foreach) to generate your textboxes, so what I would do is create a form inside that foreach this new form would contain your textbox, and foreach item you would pass the textbox id to the form submit.

something like this pseudo code:

```
foreach(item in array){
  <form action="address/"@item.Id>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit textbox"/>
  </>
}
```